# Remove annotations from Java sources

Tags: java, android, hibernate, annotations

I need to import the data model to an android project. The problem is that it was written using annotations which android does not use.

I have sources full of annotations like:

```
@NotNull
@Email
@Length(min = 3, max = 100)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@NotNull
@Length(min = 3, max = 100)
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
```

Is there a way, a tool or something to remove all this annotations programmatically? Because I have hundreds of files to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use any text editor supporting find-and-replace by regex. Even your favorite IDE could have such option.

2) More effort but more flexible. Write a simple utility doing the same. I recommend to use any script language like ruby, python etc. Of course Java is an option too.

Answer (score 0):

Do a file search with Regex and replace them with empty String accordingly perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Two options to allow you to use the code as is:

1. Add the [javax.validation jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA) to your project.
2. Or you can write your own annotations in the same package as hibernate uses.

You'll only need to write a dozen of so empty annotations to cover all used I should think, example:

```
package javax.validation.constraints;

public @interface NotNull {
}
```